# xlsxwriter: Functions VLOOKUP, SUMIF shows #NAME? error

Tags: python, vlookup, xlsx, xlsxwriter, sumifs

I am working with a python script which uses `xlsxwriter` for generating a MS Excel file on the fly. I have now almost finished my task by now struck at function error in the generated Excel file. The functions `VLOOKUP` and `SUMIF` were converted wrongly and when I manually replace any character in the cells (in the formulae) the `#NAME?` error disappear and actual value is displayed. The MWE of the python script is pasted below:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: latin-1 -*-

import xlsxwriter

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('test.xlsx', {'strings_to_numbers': True})
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Summary')

worksheet1.write_string('A1', 'Head A')
worksheet1.write_string('B1', 'Head B')
worksheet1.write_string('C1', 'Head C')
worksheet1.write_string('A2', '001')
worksheet1.write('B2', '1000')
worksheet1.write('C2', 'Tom')
worksheet1.write_string('A3', '002')
worksheet1.write('B3', '1050')
worksheet1.write('C3', 'Jerry')
worksheet1.write_string('A4', '001')
worksheet1.write('B4', '100')
worksheet1.write('C4', 'Tom')
worksheet1.write_string('A5', '002')
worksheet1.write('B5', '150')
worksheet1.write('C5', 'Jerry')

worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Test')

worksheet2.write_string('A1', 'Head A')
worksheet2.write_string('B1', 'Head B')
worksheet2.write_string('C1', 'Head C')
for i in range(2):
    worksheet2.write_string('A%s' % (i + 2), str('%03d' % (i + 1)))
    worksheet2.write_formula('B%s' % (i + 2), '=SUMIF(Summary.A2:A100,A%s,Summary.B2:B100)' % (i + 2))
    worksheet2.write_formula('C%s' % (i + 2), '=VLOOKUP(A%s,Summary.A2:C100,3,0)' % (i + 2))

workbook.close()
```

Even if I give `=SUMIF(Summary.A2:A100,A%s,Summary.B2:B100)` in the python script it appear as `=SUMIF(summary.a2:a100,a%s,summary.b2:b100)` in the XLSX file. Same is the case with `VLOOKUP`. Can anyone help me to fix this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The formula syntax isn't correct. It should be:

```
=SUMIF(Summary!A2:A100,...
```

I.e., you should use `!` not `.`.

Comment: OMG, it took me ages to figure out this error. Especially since I am using LibreOffice, which is using `.` rather than `!` internally.